# Indefinite orthogonal group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, book-recommendation

I'd like to learn more about the indefinite orthogonal group but can't find a good book which covers the topic. The minimum would be that it covers the basic theorems and proofs concerning the group (such as. $O(p,q)\cong O(q,p), \forall p,q\in \mathbb{N}$, and so on), ideally it would also have some links to physics and explain why the group is important. If the book would cover the group just as a part of a section or something like that it would be fine as well.

Can anyone recommend a book that goes in that direction?

Thanks in advance, Sito.

Comment: I think you might find some answers, as well as some references, in the book(s) ***Foundations of Differential Geometry,vol. I & II***, by Kobiyashi and Nomizu.  Cheers!

Comment: I think that O'Neill's *Semi-Riemannian Geometry With Applications to Relativity* has something about ${\rm O}(p,q)$ in chapter 9.

Comment: I second O'Neill chapter 9, which covers the connectivity properties and Lie algebra of $O(p,q)$. Chapter 7 of *Matrices: Theory and Applications* by Denis Serre also proves the connectivity properties and shows that $O(p,q)$ is homeomorphic to $O(p)\times O(q)\times \mathbb{R}^n$.